# C# force httprequest to specific machine via dns

Tags: c#, dns

I have a machine farm like,

> Machine1,MySite.com
>
> Machine2,MySite.com
>
> Machine3,MySite.com

Normally if I enter mysite.com and send my request this time, myrequest goes and works one of this machine

If it is possible ,what I want to do that,

> Like HttpClient a=new httpclient(); a.baseurl=mysite.com;

Force dns for this request ,only go to Machine 3,

Can I do that for request specific?

Comment: I assume there is a load balancer that is redirecting different requests to different servers. A common approach would be to redirect your proxy to a specific path or add a specific cookie to the URL and have the proxy redirect the request to the specific machine. What are you using for sending traffic to different machines?

Comment: Yes I have a loadbalancer to do this normally.But If possible I want to do this change only with software .

Comment: Since the load balancer is the one making this shot - the load balancer needs to be involved in it. HAProxy and other commonly used tools know how to do this but cooperation is required.

Comment: Loadbalancer has performance issue with this usage,because every request it has to check some parameters,I am looking another way to do this

Comment: Are those machines exposed to the internet? If so, why not just call the specific one directly? Like: Like HttpClient a=new httpclient(); a.baseurl=machine3address.com;

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the machine you are running this from can physically hit by IP the backend servers, you can easily accomplish this with a host entry.

Edit the servers HOSTS file to have this entry
10.10.10.10     mysite.com

where "10.10.10.10" is the IP of the server you want to connect to.

The nice part about this workaround is you don't have to make any code changes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DNS to send packets to any machine you want as long as the machine has an address on the network.

If you have some packets that you want to send directly to Machine1.MySite.com, Machine1 would need an externally accessible IP address and your DNS would need to have an entry for Machine1's IP Address.

There's no technical reason that you can't have machines behind a load balancer while also having one or more of them available directly.

However this has nothing to do with C#. There is no way to make your C# application connect with a machine that isn't accessible. The machine needs an accessible IP address and optionally a name that can be looked up to resolve the address.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Basically I want to do something like,Adding HttpRequest to Host info seems work

> HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
>
> ```
>         client.BaseAddress =new Uri(@"https://10.10.10.10/");
>
>         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Host = "mysite.com";
>
>         string RequestUri = "api/General/CityList";
>
>        var y= client.GetAsync(RequestUri).Result;
>
>         var responseBody2 = y.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
> ```

Comment: For https, this method will work as long as there is a valid cert on the other end. It needs to match the host in the URL, not the host in the request header. So for this it would need to be a cert that is valid for **10.10.10.10**.